# Keeping the largest string out of string overlaps in R

Tags: r

I have an R `data.frame` object of 5131 rows with four columns, sample of which is as follows:

```
1 X  12830000  12910000  C
2 X  12960000  13510000  C
3 X  13525000  13675000  C
4 X  13670000  13715000  C
5 X  13670000  13770000  E2
6 X  13670000  14050000  E3
7 X  13765000  14050000  E1
8 X  13910000  14050000  E1
9 X  13940000  14050000  C
10 X  15360000  15590000  E3
```

This is a genomic `.bed` file, with column 2 being the start position coordinate of a stretch of DNA, column 3 being the end position, and column 4 some meta-information about it. So this could be imagined as pieces of strings that overlap with each other, according to their coordinates.

I want to write an R script which does the following:

If there is an overlap between rows of more than 40000 among each other, than choose the row with the longest length amongst the overlap. In the **sorted** sample data, moving down sequentially, there is more than 40000 overlap between row 4 and 5, row 5 and 6, row 6 and 7, row 7 and 8, and row 8 and row 9, amongst which row 6 is the longest. Amongst 4 and 5, row 5 is longest, so I keep 5. Between row 5 and 6, 6 is the longest, so I keep 6. I keep doing this 
until I find a row with less than 4000 overlap, and pick the longest among them.

So my new dataframe should be something like this:

```
1 X  12830000  12910000  C
2 X  12960000  13510000  C
3 X  13525000  13675000  C
6 X  13670000  14050000  E3  <- (keeping the longest one)
10 X  15360000  15590000  E3
```

I tried to do the following so far:

```
output_4 <- fr_t[NULL,] 
for(i in 1:nrow(fr_t)-1){ 
if(isTRUE(fr_t[i+1,]$V3-fr_t[i,]$V2<40000||fr_t[i,]$V3-fr_t[i+1,]$V2 < 40000)) {
if(isTRUE((fr_t[i+1,]$V3-fr_t[i+1,]$V2)>(fr_t[i+2,]$V3-fr_t[i+2,]$V2))){
next
}
next
}
output_4 <- rbind(output_4, fr_t[i+2,])
}  #fr_t is my original dataframe
```

I can't figure out how to iterate my `i` to go until the rows that overlap, to keep the longest one.

Also, how can I save the meta-information in column 4 as a matrix of overlaps? For example, a new dataframe as followng:

```
E3  C  E2  E1  E1  C
```

The first column being the column 4 of the largest row, and all the other columns being the column 4 of the overlaps inside it? This would require an object of varying column numbers. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: there are a larger number of packages on https://www.bioconductor.org/ which you should be aware of, some are specifically for genomic range analysis.

Comment: Could you let me know which one to use for this purpose?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Why does row 4 disappear? The overlap with row 3 is only 5000, and there is zero overlap with row 9. Or am I missing something? Also, how does the last column come into play? Are overlaps column 4 dependent, i.e. only remove rows if overlap is `>40000` *and* column 4 IDs match?

Comment: @MauritsEvers My dataframe is numerically sorted. When I move down from row 3 to row 4, the overlap is only 5000. Between row 4 and row 5, it is more than 40000. So I want to keep the longest between the two- in this case row 5. Then I compare row 5 and 6( since the overlap is more than 40000 again), and I obtain row 6. I keep doing this until I find a row which has an overlap less than 40000. In my case, after getting row 6 as the longest, I do not find any other row (till 9, because row 9 and 10 don't overlap by the 40000 threshold) which is longer than it. So row 6 is my answer.

Comment: So can you just confirm that entries in column 4 don't have to match between overlapping ranges?

Comment: @MauritsEvers oh yes,apologies! No, column 4 has nothing to do with the overlap. They are just meta information!

Comment: I'm still confused; in your main post you state *"there is more than 40000 overlap between row 4 and row 9"*. But rows 4 and 9 have zero overlap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169871/discussion-between-rishi-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I completely agree with @zacdav's comment. Take a look at the R/Bioconductor package `GenomicRanges`; it has been developed exactly for these kind of operations. There exist some great tutorials, e.g. [here](http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesIntroduction.pdf), and [here](http://bioconductor.org/packages/3.7/bioc/vignettes/GenomicRanges/inst/doc/GenomicRangesHOWTOs.pdf).

As to your question, the following reproduces your expected output:

```
# Your sample data as a data.frame
df <- read.table(text =
    "1 X  12830000  12910000  C
2 X  12960000  13510000  C
3 X  13525000  13675000  C
4 X  13670000  13715000  C
5 X  13670000  13770000  E2
6 X  13670000  14050000  E3
7 X  13765000  14050000  E1
8 X  13910000  14050000  E1
9 X  13940000  14050000  C
10 X  15360000  15590000  E3", header = F, row.names = 1)

# Convert data.frame to GRanges
library(GenomicRanges);
gr <- with(df, GRanges(
    seqnames = df[, 1],
    IRanges(start = df[, 2], end = df[, 3]),
    id = df[, 4]))

# Find overlapping regions within gr
hits <- findOverlaps(gr, gr, minoverlap = 40000);

# Remove self-overlapping hits
hits <- hits[queryHits(hits) != subjectHits(hits)];

# Determine features that are shorter than the overlapping feature
mcols(hits)$queryWidth = width(gr[queryHits(hits)]);
mcols(hits)$subjectWidth = width(gr[subjectHits(hits)]);
mcols(hits)$hit <- ifelse(
    mcols(hits)$queryWidth < mcols(hits)$subjectWidth, 
    queryHits(hits), 
    subjectHits(hits));

# Remove those shorter overlapping features
gr.final <- gr[-unique(mcols(hits)$hit)];
gr.final;
#GRanges object with 5 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#      seqnames               ranges strand |       id
#         <Rle>            <IRanges>  <Rle> | <factor>
#  [1]        X [12830000, 12910000]      * |        C
#  [2]        X [12960000, 13510000]      * |        C
#  [3]        X [13525000, 13675000]      * |        C
#  [4]        X [13670000, 14050000]      * |       E3
#  [5]        X [15360000, 15590000]      * |       E3
```

If you want to convert `gr.final` back into a `data.frame` you can use `as.data.frame(gr.final)`.